# Visual Studio 2017 finds phantom xml errors in edmx file

Tags: xml, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, edmx

When I build the Entity Frameworks project in my solution, verbiage in the output window indicates that *the build was successful*.  But if I go look at the error list, I see that this error appears twice:

> The 'edmx:Diagrams' start tag on line 6 position 6 does not match the
>   end tag of 'Diagram'. Line 284, position 9.

There are thousands of lines in this edmx file, but here's line 6:

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
```

And here's line 284:

```
<PropertyRef Name="CommunityRegionalCorpId" />
```

The only "Diagrams" tags in the file are on line 12,273:

```
<Diagrams></Diagrams>
```

No edmx:Diagram or edmx:Diagrams tags exist anywhere in the edmx file.

Things I've tried:

- I've exited and restarted Visual Studio.
- I've modifed and re-built the edmx file, both by hand and from the designer (diagram).
- I've cleaned the solution and built it again.
- I've taken a near-identical copy of the edmx file from someone else on the project who does not see these build errors.

---

**UPDATE: this issue has come and gone for no apparent reason over the past few months.  As of 3/3/2020, it is gone again.**

Comment: Please don't say you went into the code for the edmx file and removed/ edited it? Please tell me you simply used the diagram view it gives you

Comment: If you insist, I won't say it. :)  The error message recently went away without any changes made to the edmx file, however.  It has appeared and disappeared in the past under circumstances that I find similarly mysterious. Once, months ago, the only "change" I had to make was quitting and restarting VS.  But that didn't help this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue on VS2019 EF6. After searching and finding no reference to "Diagram" in the edmx file, I looked at the edmx.diagram file.  Sure enough I extra  tags in the last few lines of the file. I suspect that there was a fault merge somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean a faulty source control (e.g., Git) merge?  That might well have happened.  I'm not on that project anymore, but this answer is plausible and matches the facts.  I'll keep it under my hat, thank you.

Comment: I just ran into the same thing.  Despite verifying a merge from master into dev, the designer would break with the dev branch checked out but be fine with the master branch checked out.  It showed some elements in the xml weren't matching; I don't know why only in one branch. I did git merge origin/master -- ./edmxprojectfolder/ and that cleaned it up. The edmx shows as modified in git so...  I dunno... weird!

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was in the [Modelname].edmx.diagram file, a bad merge had duplicated the Diagram tag.

```html
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram DiagramId="b000c7d258aa4f45ae3d668237792135" Name="Diagram1" ZoomLevel="68">
      <Diagram DiagramId="b000c7d258aa4f45ae3d668237792135" Name="Diagram1" ZoomLevel="63">
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="M1_C2Model.uTaskPriority" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="2.75" IsExpanded="false" />
```